# How to access property of a subclass

Tags: c#, class, abstract-class

I have 1 abstract class 'Book' and 2 subclasses 'Comic' and 'Novel' extended from first abstract class.
In the main method I have to create array of books that will store instances of  comics and novels.

My problem is that I don't know how to access a variable price of class 'Comic'.
I have getters in 'Comic' class but i can access only the variables which are part of parent class 'Book'.

```
abstract class Book
{
    private string title;
    private string author;
    ...
}

class Comic : Book
{
    private double price;
    ...
}



static void Main(string[] args) {
   ...
   for (int i = 0; i < books.Length; i++) {
        if (books[i] is Comic)
           Console.WriteLine("Price of comic is..."); 
           // Here i want to access books[i].price or books[i].Price with getter.
   }

   ...
}
```

Comment: Why dont you add a virtual property or a protected variable named `Price` to `Book` class? Every book has a price, right?

Comment: `Cast` it to type `Comic`

Comment: You cant access anything if it is private, but those are not properties

Comment: Why is the price private at all? You could make it a property which can only be read `public double Price{get;}`. Then you can't change it from outside.

Comment: @Rango It looks like the OP is using the old style of `private fields` with `Get/Set` methods instead of `auto-properties`, if you read their comment line, it appears that they have a `Get` method called `Price()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to change the accessibility of the price field, or create a public property, then, you can use the **Pattern Matching** feature (check it on the 'if' line, I wrote a **c** after the Comic type, that cast the Book to a Comic if the 'is' check is true, and you can use that variable inside the 'if' statement):

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
...
    for (int i = 0; i < books.Length; i++) {
        if (books[i] is Comic c)
           Console.WriteLine("Price of comic is..." + c.price); 
           // Here i want to access books[i].price or books[i].Price with getter.
    }
...
}
```

Comment: @DjordjeGligorijevic also mark it as the answer so that this question is marked "aswered"

Comment: `c.Price` might be valid since `price` seems to be a private field

Comment: I will but i need to wait 5 minutes until i can do.

Answer (score 0):

Private variables (as shown in your Book class) are not accessible outside of the scope of the class. This means that, for example, *book.title* will display an error.

To make your "price" property available, I would first recommend bringing that variable to the Book class instead (as it can be assumed that all books or derived classes should have a price).
After which you can create an public property as follows:

```
public double Price { get; set; }
```

This will expose the Price property when attempting to access objects within your books collection.

As to access your price in your main method, something like the following would probably suit:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
...
    for (int i = 0; i < books.Length; i++) {
        if (books[i] is Comic)
           Comic c = books[i] as Comic;
           Console.WriteLine("Price of comic is..." + c.Price); 
    }
...
}
```

Quickly, accessors in C# tend to follow the same sort of rules as with a lot of  languages with similar syntax (such as Java or C++):

**Public :** can be accessed at any level of scope that utilizes an instance of that class.

**Private :** can be accessed only within the scope of the class, and cannot be directly accessed outside of it.